# C# XMLDocument Assistance

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I have the following XML File.

```
  <THE_SETTINGS>
    <SOURCE_FOLDER>\SERVER_NAME\folder1\</SOURCE_FOLDER>
    <NETWORK_DEVICE>eth1<SERIAL>A0123456</SERIAL></NETWORK_DEVICE>
  </THE_SETTINGS>
```

In my C# Code I read in the XML document as follows

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument(); 
xmldoc.Load("PATH_TO_XML");
```

I can successfully read the SOURCE_FOLDER value and SERIAL into variables, however when I am getting the incorrect value when attempting to read the NETWORK_DEVICE field.
My Expected result for the network_device_name should be network_device_name=eth1 but I'm getting the combined response of network_device and serial. I.E eth1A0123456

```
string source_folder_value;
string network_device_name;
string serial;
if(xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//THE_SETTINGS/SOURCE_FOLDER") != null )
{
    //Success
    source_folder_value= xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//THE_SETTINGS/SOURCE_FOLDER").InnerText.ToString();
}
if(xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//THE_SETTINGS/NETWORK_DEVICE") != null )
{
    //Failed after this line network_device_name = "eth1A0123456"
    network_device_name= xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//THE_SETTINGS/NETWORK_DEVICE").InnerText.ToString();
}
if(xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//THE_SETTINGS/NETWORK_DEVICE/SERIAL") != null )
{
    //Success serial=A0123456
    serial= xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//THE_SETTINGS/NETWORK_DEVICE/SERIAL").InnerText.ToString();
}
```

How do I only retrieve eth1 for the network name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//THE_SETTINGS/NETWORK_DEVICE/text()
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?
I can't find any extension function /text(). This does not work

Comment: @PeterH, `network_device_name = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//THE_SETTINGS/NETWORK_DEVICE/text()").InnerText;`. Returns `eth1`. And there is no need to call `ToString()` on string object...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//THE_SETTINGS/NETWORK_DEVICE").FirstChild.InnerText
```

Comment: Can you elaborate ? why its not working or suiting your requirement.?